# Display remote hosted video/image in the Scorm

Tags: moodle, scorm, scorm1.2

I am a beginner on the Scorm. I want to access scorm content from a different server. a video/image is stored on s1 instance and accessing the content from an LMS via scorm which is hosted on a different instance, s2.

What needs to be modified in the scorm to make it accessible to the cloud-hosted scorm content?

I changed the content location path from imsmanifest.xml file. But still not access the cloud content.

The following steps are followed to update a Scorm content with cloud content.

1. Took a scorm package.
2. Unzip the scorm package and changed an mp4 video content with cloud-hosted URL. Screenshot: [image]
3. Zip the scorm and upload on a Moodle LMS.
4. Experiencing this error: [image]

It seems it is still taking the old path.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not accessible"? Do you see some sort of an error message?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have edited the comment with the error message.

Comment: Can you open the mp4 link in a browser?

Comment: Yes, I can open the link in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Listing the file file in SCORM manifest file is just to tell the LMS what files to expect in the package (and I'm not even sure if Moodle's SCORM implementation uses that information at all, or just accepts what's in the package).

For the video hosted outside the package to be accessed by the user, you need to use the full path in the HTML or javascript code used to display the video.

This isn't actually a SCORM issue, it's a run-of-the-mill HTML web page issue.